# Buffer Mp3 bytes from server to android and play it

Tags: android, signalr, audio-streaming

We want to buffer bytes of mp3 file from server; The client is an android device.
We can stream bytes using signal-R and it works fine on ios using AVFoundation.
But the problem is playing this file on android.
We tried

```
MediaPlayer and AudioTrack
```

but non of them works in this situation;

Media Player needs stream-URL, something like "example.com/test.mp3"; so we cannot use this option.

Every time we can get N bytes of Mp3 data using signal-R.
How can we play this kind of data?